# Identifying System Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

We are currently performing a clean up on our marketing cloud instance with 30 BUs.

Currently, we have a ssjs script that fetches all the data extensions and it's row count using the undocumented API mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29511/how-can-you-retrieve-number-of-records-in-a-data-extension-using-soap-api?rq=1). The use case is to delete the data extensions that are junk/test using [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_delete.htm) method. The problem is while fetching the data extensions, we are also getting a list of System data extensions(not visible on UI). Is there a way where we can identify these data extensions, so that we can exclude them from our script? I have checked the Data Extension object and it has no field to identify this.

Answer (score 2):

1. The System Data Extension (Data Views) have a name starting with an Underscore ("_Subscribers", "_Opens", etc.). Most of them are listed in [official SFMC docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5).
   Few missing from the official documentation you can find in [Zuzanna's Post](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/) and [my Docs](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-config-system-data-views)
2. Additionally take into consideration the Einstein Data Extensions if you have them enabled. Those start with either "IGO_", "PI_" and "Einstein_" prefixes.
3. If you are using Behavioral Triggers, you should also leave Data Extensions with "abandoned_" prefix

Comment: Also one more to add to the list, there are some system data extensions that start with 'dts' such as 'dts_BatchStatus_7331050'

Comment: I see you post a lot of links to a website that bears the same name as your username. Posting self-promotional links like this (without disclosing your affiliation) is considered spammy.