# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - SOAP API - Python - Usable Properties For Data Extension Object Type

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, python, documentation

Is there documentation outlining all usable fields to pass into your SOAP packet when retrieving information on the DataExtension Object Type? I thought the below link was outlining usable fields with proper naming conventions, but I've received errors indicating the fields do not exist when attempting to pass some of them through in my soap packet ("Fields" and "PartnerProperties").

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextension.html

I'm specifically looking to know if there is a field I can pass in that will let me know how many records the DataExtensions have in them, but would be curious to see all other usable fields.

I'm currently only pullng: "ObjectID", "CustomerKey", "Name", "IsSendable". What else is accesible?

```
 <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
             <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
             <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
             <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
             <Properties>Name</Properties>
             <Properties>IsSendable</Properties>
         </RetrieveRequest>
     </RetrieveRequestMsg> </s:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to know which properties of a SOAP object are "Retrievable", perform a [Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/describe.html) request. You'll need to set the SoapAction HTTP header to a value of "Describe":

**Sample Request**

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth>{{_token}}</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <DescribeRequests>
            <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
               <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
            </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
         </DescribeRequests>
      </DefinitionRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Abbreviated Response**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>DescribeResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:e6529fb1-780b-41c9-b9ae-ac22e6828859</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:3434a52e-8c6d-412f-af12-43e05fcc2d36</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-df8099fe-6608-495a-afd3-bf4484424548">
                <wsu:Created>2022-11-09T00:55:51Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-11-09T01:00:51Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <DefinitionResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <ObjectDefinition>
                <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>ObjectID</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Name>PartnerKey</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>64</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                ...
            </ObjectDefinition>
            <RequestID>ab22d494-9c1a-4ffc-8e2a-be20027ed138</RequestID>
        </DefinitionResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Properties that are retrievable for the DataExtension object are as follows:
| Property                        |
| ------------------------------- |
| ObjectID                        |
| PartnerKey                      |
| CustomerKey                     |
| Name                            |
| CreatedDate                     |
| ModifiedDate                    |
| Client.ID                       |
| Description                     |
| IsSendable                      |
| IsTestable                      |
| SendableDataExtensionField.Name |
| SendableSubscriberField.Name    |
| Template.CustomerKey            |
| CategoryID                      |
| Status                          |
| IsPlatformObject                |
| DataRetentionPeriodLength       |
| DataRetentionPeriodUnitOfMeasur |
| RowBasedRetention               |
| ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport    |
| DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod    |
| RetainUntil                     |
| DataRetentionPeriod             |

Comment: Thanks @Macca, is there a good way to determine how many records are in a DataExtension?

Comment: @CarsonW Take a look at this solutions https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29511/how-can-you-retrieve-number-of-records-in-a-data-extension-using-soap-api